# How to set Bing Webmaster Tools to ignore subdomains other than WWW?

Tags: subdomain, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

Is there a way to limit Bing Webmaster Tools to indexing only one subdomain from my clients TLD? My client has an online service that creates a subdomain for each user under their TLD, and these subdomains have tons of errors and info that is making Bing Webmaster Tools next to impossible to use.

I only want info on `www.example.com`, but Bing is giving insights on `user1.example.com`, `user1.example.com` etc...

Google Webmaster Tools allows you to focus in on a specific subdomain, so this is not an issue with GWT.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to block the urls individually under the site configuration options.

Or you could add some code to your robots.txt that only allows Bingbot to access the www.example.com.